# A query that compares the LAG value and fills the sub column with data if there is a difference?

Tags: sql, oracle

> A query that compares the LAG value and fills the sub column with data if there is a difference?

```
WITH A AS (
    SELECT 'GOLD' AS Title, 1 AS RNUM, 555.4 AS VALUE1, null AS DIFF, null AS LAG FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'GOLD' AS Title, 2 AS RNUM, 555.4 AS VALUE1, 0 AS DIFF, 555.4 AS LAG FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GOLD' AS Title, 3 AS RNUM, 555.4 AS VALUE1, 0 AS DIFF, 555.4 AS LAG FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'GOLD' AS Title, 4 AS RNUM, 556 AS VALUE1, 0.6 AS DIFF, 555.4 AS LAG FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GOLD' AS Title, 5 AS RNUM, 556 AS VALUE1, 0 AS DIFF, 556 AS LAG FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GOLD' AS Title, 6 AS RNUM, 556 AS VALUE1, 0 AS DIFF, 556 AS LAG FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GOLD' AS Title, 7 AS RNUM, 556.7 AS VALUE1, 0.7 AS DIFF, 556 AS LAG FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GOLD' AS Title, 8 AS RNUM, 556.7 AS VALUE1, 0 AS DIFF,556.7 AS LAG FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GOLD' AS Title, 9 AS RNUM, 557.3 AS VALUE1, 0.6 AS DIFF, 556.7 AS LAG FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SILVER' AS Title, 1 AS RNUM, 400.3 AS VALUE1, null AS DIFF, null AS LAG FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SILVER' AS Title, 2 AS RNUM, 401.3 AS VALUE1, 1.0 AS DIFF, 400.3 AS LAG FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SILVER' AS Title, 3 AS RNUM, 401.3 AS VALUE1, 0 AS DIFF, 401.3 AS LAG FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SILVER' AS Title, 4 AS RNUM, 401.3 AS VALUE1, 0 AS DIFF, 401.3 AS LAG FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SILVER' AS Title, 5 AS RNUM, 402.2 AS VALUE1, 0.9 AS DIFF, 401.3 AS LAG FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SILVER' AS Title, 6 AS RNUM, 403.2 AS VALUE1, 1.0 AS DIFF, 402.2 AS LAG FROM DUAL
)
```

> Using A, I want to get the same result as B.

If the data in the DIFF column is greater than 0 (or according to a condition), I want to fill the value in the AccMaxNo column with the RNUM value in the DIFF column.

```
    A
```

| Title | RNUM | VALUE1 | DIFF | LAG | AccMaxNo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GOLD | 1 | 555.4 | null | null |  |
| GOLD | 2 | 555.4 | 0 | 555.4 |  |
| GOLD | 3 | 555.4 | 0 | 555.4 |  |
| GOLD | 4 | 556 | 0.6 | 555.4 |  |
| GOLD | 5 | 556 | 0 | 556 |  |
| GOLD | 6 | 556 | 0 | 556 |  |
| GOLD | 7 | 556.7 | 0.7 | 556 |  |
| GOLD | 8 | 556.7 | 0 | 556.7 |  |
| GOLD | 9 | 557.3 | 0.6 | 556.7 |  |
| SILVER | 1 | 400.3 | null | null |  |
| SILVER | 2 | 401.3 | 1.0 | 400.3 |  |
| SILVER | 3 | 401.3 | 0 | 401.3 |  |
| SILVER | 4 | 401.3 | 0 | 401.3 |  |
| SILVER | 5 | 402.2 | 0.9 | 401.3 |  |
| SILVER | 6 | 403.2 | 1.0 | 402.2 |  |

```
QUERY B
```

| Title | RNUM | VALUE1 | DIFF | LAG | AccMaxNo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GOLD | 1 | 555.4 | null | null | **4** |
| GOLD | 2 | 555.4 | 0 | 555.4 | **4** |
| GOLD | 3 | 555.4 | 0 | 555.4 | **4** |
| **GOLD** | **4** | 556 | **0.6** | 555.4 | **4** |
| GOLD | 5 | 556 | 0 | 556 | **7** |
| GOLD | 6 | 556 | 0 | 556 | **7** |
| **GOLD** | **7** | 556.7 | **0.7** | 556 | **7** |
| GOLD | 8 | 556.7 | 0 | 556.7 | **9** |
| **GOLD** | **9** | 557.3 | **0.6** | 556.7 | **9** |
| SILVER | 1 | 400.3 | null | null | **2** |
| **SILVER** | **2** | 401.3 | **1.0** | 400.3 | **2** |
| SILVER | 3 | 401.3 | 0 | 401.3 | **5** |
| SILVER | 4 | 401.3 | 0 | 401.3 | **5** |
| **SILVER** | **5** | 402.2 | **0.9** | 401.3 | **5** |
| **SILVER** | **6** | 403.2 | **1.0** | 402.2 | **6** |

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can preform row-by-row processing using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT title,
       rnum,
       value1,
       value1 - lag AS diff,
       lag,
       MAX(rnum) OVER (PARTITION BY title, mno) AS accmaxno
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY title
  ORDER BY rnum
  MEASURES
    PREV(value1) AS lag,
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS mno
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ((^ first_row | same_value)* any_row)
  DEFINE
    same_value AS PREV(value1) = value1
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Title, RNUM, VALUE1) AS
SELECT 'GOLD',   1, 555.4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GOLD',   2, 555.4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GOLD',   3, 555.4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GOLD',   4, 556 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GOLD',   5, 556 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GOLD',   6, 556 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GOLD',   7, 556.7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GOLD',   8, 556.7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GOLD',   9, 557.3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SILVER', 1, 400.3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SILVER', 2, 401.3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SILVER', 3, 401.3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SILVER', 4, 401.3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SILVER', 5, 402.2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SILVER', 6, 403.2 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| TITLE | RNUM | VALUE1 | DIFF | LAG | ACCMAXNO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GOLD | 1 | 555.4 | *null* | *null* | 4 |
| GOLD | 2 | 555.4 | 0 | 555.4 | 4 |
| GOLD | 3 | 555.4 | 0 | 555.4 | 4 |
| GOLD | 4 | 556 | .6 | 555.4 | 4 |
| GOLD | 5 | 556 | 0 | 556 | 7 |
| GOLD | 6 | 556 | 0 | 556 | 7 |
| GOLD | 7 | 556.7 | .7 | 556 | 7 |
| GOLD | 8 | 556.7 | 0 | 556.7 | 9 |
| GOLD | 9 | 557.3 | .6 | 556.7 | 9 |
| SILVER | 1 | 400.3 | *null* | *null* | 2 |
| SILVER | 2 | 401.3 | 1 | 400.3 | 2 |
| SILVER | 3 | 401.3 | 0 | 401.3 | 5 |
| SILVER | 4 | 401.3 | 0 | 401.3 | 5 |
| SILVER | 5 | 402.2 | .9 | 401.3 | 5 |
| SILVER | 6 | 403.2 | 1 | 402.2 | 6 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/k2JzPWtF)

Answer (score 0):

The analytical function ***FIRST_VALUE*** is very practical for this purpose.

- ***NULLIF*** function here transforms all diff values 0 to null
- Then ***IGNORE NULLS*** clause used with FIRST_VALUE ignore all rows where NULLIF(diff, 0) is null
- Finally, the windowing clause ***ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING*** allows the function to be restricted to the rows concerned as required.

```sql
SELECT a.*
     , FIRST_VALUE( 
           CASE WHEN NULLIF(diff, 0) IS NOT NULL THEN rnum ELSE NULL END 
         ) IGNORE NULLS OVER(
                PARTITION BY title ORDER BY rnum 
                ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
            ) AccMaxNo
FROM A
;
```

[***demo on db<>fiddle***](https://dbfiddle.uk/xT7yA2Gx)

Comment: You're welcome. Please if my answer solved your problem, mark it as resolved.